# Editing resolution of JIRA issue using Transition throws exception

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I have two JIRA project for eg. `DEV` and `CLIENT`. I want to set the resolution of issue in `CLIENT` project to `DONE` when the resolution of issue in `DEV` project changes to `DONE`.

For this I have done following code :

```
public void changeTransition(com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue devIssue, Issue clientIssue, JiraRestClient restClient) {
    IssueRestClient issueClient = restClient.getIssueClient();
    Iterable<Transition> transitions = issueClient.getTransitions(clientIssue.getTransitionsUri()).claim();
    final Transition doneIssueTransition = getTransitionByName(transitions, "Done");  //this returns done Transition
    if (doneIssueTransition != null) {
        ImmutableList.Builder<FieldInput> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
        builder.add(new FieldInput(IssueFieldId.RESOLUTION_FIELD, ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("name", devIssue.getResolution().getName())));
        ImmutableList<FieldInput> fieldInputs = builder.build();
        TransitionInput transitionInput = new TransitionInput(doneIssueTransition.getId(), fieldInputs, prepareComment(devIssue));
        issueClient.transition(clientIssue.getTransitionsUri(), transitionInput).claim();
    }
}
```

The exception that I get is :

```
Field 'resolution' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
```

is there anything wrong with the code? what this exception signifies? what changes should I make to get this resolved?

Comment: Are `DEV` and `CLIENT` sharing the same Workflow? If not, the ID's for transitions may vary. Be sure to look up whether the ID's are actually the same.

Comment: @SgtTrace yes both share the same workflow. About the transition ids, I am using the transition id of `done transition` from client project, so this will be fine right?

Comment: Well, you have to keep in mind, that transitions are from one specific state to another specific state. So if eg you want to transition from `in Progress` to `Done` the ID is different from the transition `Watiting` to `Done`. So what you have to do is basically switch according to the tupel of destination and source state and then transition accordingly. This might take various transitions according to the states youre using.

Comment: @SgtTrace I am getting same exception for any field that I try to update.